# Thread with queue for dealing with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, background, queue

Right now I have a lot of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT methods in one class. They all share one Connection, one DataReader and one Command. But while downloading data from DB, or uploading data them freeze the UI. It was ok on local network, but since it using external server for DB, it freezes sometimes. So I want to make all MySQL class on another thread.

I need something like DoThisInAnotherThread(mysql.UpdateTable). But there has to be some kind of queue, since all methods use the same Connection and the same DataReader. And making every method to make its own connection dont look like the best solution.

I'm looking for the best and easiest solution. Something like queue for Tasks, which will be checked by another thread and executed, while it will not be empty.

I tried BackgroundWorker, but there is no queue. I heard something about starting own thread, but I dont see a way, how to make it run and wait for tasks.

Thank you.

Comment: The way I did this was to build a Windows Service.  I put a queue in it, and when I received a service request I placed it into the queue.  The service spun off threads as needed to process the queue items; I could limit the number of concurrent threads to whatever I wanted, and a persistent connection to the database was certainly possible.

Comment: That said, databases are designed to handle multiple connections.  If you're spinning off threads to get work done, the work is almost certainly heavier than the connection.

Comment: I dont want permanent connection to database, because I think this is not the securest way to work with database. But create connection object in every method means a lot of redundancy code. So I dont want this too. Do you know at least about how to store called methods? In which object. I have to see progress of the tasks too. When updating, I dont have to get any return value, but while selecting yes. So I would like to make queue of called methods and by timer checking if the called method is still in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a work queue, which will execute all work on a single thread. There you can keep single sql connection, and synchronization will be simple, since all commands are executed sequentially.

Look at the example WorkQueue implementation below (note that it is missing exception handling):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var q = new WorkQueue();
    q.Execute(() => Console.WriteLine("A"));
    q.Execute(() => Console.WriteLine("B"));
    Task<int> t = q.Execute(() => 33);

    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    q.Dispose();
  }

}

public class WorkQueue : IDisposable
{
  private readonly Thread thread;
  private readonly BlockingCollection<Action> queue;
  public WorkQueue()
  {
    this.queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
    this.thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    this.thread.Start();
  }

  public Task<T> Execute<T>(Func<T> f)
  {
    if (this.queue.IsCompleted) return null;
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    Execute(() => source.SetResult(f()));
    return source.Task;
  }

  public void Execute(Action f)
  {
    if (this.queue.IsCompleted) return;
    this.queue.Add(f);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    this.queue.CompleteAdding();
    this.thread.Join();
  }

  private void DoWork()
  {
    foreach (var action in this.queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
      action();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, there is a better [implementation of work queue using TaskScheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualizeparallel/archive/2011/02/14/a-taskscheduler-that-limits-the-number-of-threads.aspx) available

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to:

- implement a class representing the result of a sql query, say `SQLResult`, which would be further specialized into each type of query.
- specialize `Task<SQLResult>` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28VS.100%29.aspx)) : the class sports the API needed to query the state of completion of a task.
- use a `TaskScheduler` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), which carries the queuing semantics you are looking for.